# how to prevent that intellij delete all blank line?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, indentation, blank-line

When I write code, I indent Also the blank lines with tabs.
But `IntelliJ` when I press delete button cancel entire line.
Is it possible to prevent this action? I would like that `Intellij` delete space or tabs one at a time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

file -> settings -> editor -> general -> smart keys -> uncheck backspace smart indent